# HTTP File upload cannot parse form data?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to upload `pdf` with password using `html` form to my `cloud function` but while parsing both from request body return unidentified error.

This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<!-- curretly using emulator but the error is same if deployed-->
  <form action="http://localhost:5000/ecutter-web/us-central1/test" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="sfile" accept=".pdf">
    <input type="text" name="spass">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is how the res looks if i send it back with body `res.send(req.body):

```
-----------------------------1282136010350931161350789983 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sfile"; filename="Aad.pdf" Content-Type: application/pdf %PDF-1.4 ..(returned as text here).. -----------------------------1282136010350931161350789983 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="spass" PDF12345 -----------------------------1282136010350931161350789983--
```

but when i try to parse single of them using `req.body.sfile` or `req.body.spass` it returns undefined

Why ?

Comment: I responded to a similar question, for Excel files, here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/61569399/9513617 But it is for C# / .NET

Comment: You need to include more code snippets of how you handle the request. My guess is that you need to use something to parse the request body first.